# Python Auto Importing

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Perl's AUTOLOAD in Python (**getattr** on a module)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024455/perls-autoload-in-python-getattr-on-a-module)

I'm coming from a PHP background and attempting to learn Python, and I want to be sure to do things the "Python way" instead of how i've developed before.

My question comes from the fact in PHP5 you can set up your code so if you attempt to call a class that doesn't exist in the namespace, a function will run first that will load the class in and allow you to continue on as if it were already loaded.  the advantages to this is classes weren't loaded unless they were called, and you didn't have to worry about loading classes before using them.

In python, there's alot of emphasis on the import statement, is it bad practice to attempt an auto importing trick with python, to alleviate the need for an import statement?  I've found [this module](http://www.connellybarnes.com/code/autoimp/) that offers auto importing, however I dont know if that's the best way of doing it, or if auto importing of modules is something that is recommended, thoughts?

Comment: This is a repeat discussion from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024455/autoload-in-python

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question (this is about auto import (of modules) whreas the other one is about autoloading/lazy loading) and the solution is not answered there.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Imports serve at least two other important purposes besides making the modules or contents of the modules available:

1. They serve as a sort of declaration of intent -- "this module uses services from this other module" or "this module uses services belonging to a certain class" -- e.g. if you are doing a security review for socket-handling code, you can begin by only looking at modules that import `socket` (or other networking-related modules)
2. Imports serve as a proxy for the complexity of a module. If you find yourself with dozens of lines of imports, it may be time to reconsider your separation of concerns within the module, or within your application as a whole. This is also a good reason to avoid "`from foo import *`"-type imports.

Answer (score 11):

In Python, people usually avoid auto imports, just because it is not worth the effort. You may slightly remove startup costs, but otherwise, there is no (or should be no) significant effect. If you have modules that are expensive to import and do a lot of stuff that doesn't need to be done, rather rewrite the module than delay importing it.

That said, there is nothing inherently wrong with auto imports. Because of the proxy nature, there may be some pitfalls (e.g. when looking at a thing that has not been imported yet). Several auto importing libraries are floating around.

Answer (score 1):

If you are learning Python and want to do things the Python way, then just import the modules.  It's *very* unusual to find autoimports in Python code.

Answer (score 1):

You could auto-import the modules, but the most I have ever needed to import was about 10, and that is after I tacked features on top of the original program. You won't be importing a lot, and the names are very easy to remember.

Comment: That is simply not true for projects even just a little bigger. I've even once worked on a project where there was (almost) no python file without import.