# load module without import when class is needed

Tags: python

I am using python 3.3

I have a folder `model` with several modules, each with one class defined in it. The class has the same name as the module.

Now I want it so that when in the main script I do `foo=Foo()` that automatically the class  module `model.Foo` is loaded with the effect of `from model.Foo import Foo`

How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually not a good idea to have automatic import. How would the python interpreter know that `Foo` is `model.Foo` ?

One way to "ease" importing classes is to load them in the module `__init__.py`

Ex:
[https://github.com/masom/shopify-trois/blob/master/shopify_trois/models](https://github.com/masom/shopify-trois/blob/master/shopify_trois/models/__init__.py)

Someone else asked a similar question: [Python Auto Importing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493888/python-auto-importing)

Answer (score 0):

While agreeing with Martin's warning about doing so, if you really want to dynamically import code, have a look at the [`imp` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/imp.html).