# How to autoload python packages

Tags: python

I'm currently learning Python and using spyder 3 as editor.
There are several python packages that I use regularly and, to avoid including them in each new script, I put a list of imports in a script file called autoload.py and hoped that by calling autoload.py the packages in question are automatically loaded. Unfortunately this does not work.

To illustrate, the file autoload.py contains:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from functools import reduce
import collections as clct
import numpy as np
import platform
```

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Auto Importing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493888/python-auto-importing)

Answer (score 1):

Simple, autoload.py contains:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from functools import reduce
import collections as clct
import numpy as np
import platform
```

Your file.py contains:

```
from autoload import *
```

file.py load autoload.py content, but surely your IDE throw syntax error before running code. If you try to run, works perfectly. I have tested it in PyCharm and it works.

Anyway, I have to say you that is very bad practice.

Regards.

Comment: Ok, I get it now.
If I use "from autoload import *" it works without the "autoload" prefix. If I use "import autoload" then I need to prefix any of its parameters with "autoload". This solves my other query on global variables.
Thanks.

Comment: I did twice but apparently I need have "some reputation" first :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Spyder 3.1.4(Python 3.6):

autoload.py

```
import sys
import easygui
```

test.py

```
import autoload
print('test')
print(easygui.msgbox('Hello'))
sys.exit()
```

Like others have mentioned, this is probably not a good approach.