# Skip subdirectory in python import

Tags: python, import

Ok, so I'm trying to change this:

```
app/
    - lib.py
    - models.py
    - blah.py
```

Into this:

```
app/
    - __init__.py
    - lib.py
    - models/
        - __init__.py
        - user.py
        - account.py
        - banana.py
    - blah.py
```

And still be able to import my models using `from app.models import User` rather than having to change it to `from app.models.user import User` all over the place. Basically, I want everything to treat the package as a single module, but be able to navigate the code in separate files for development ease.

The reason I can't do something like add `for file in __all__: from file import *` into **init**.py is I have circular references between the model files. A fix I don't want is to import those models from within the functions that use them. But that's super ugly. Let me give you an example:

user.py

```
...
from app.models import Banana
...
```

banana.py

```
...
from app.models import User
...
```

I wrote a quick pre-processing script that grabs all the files, re-writes them to put imports at the top, and puts it into models.py, but that's hardly an improvement, since now my stack traces don't show the line number I actually need to change.

Any ideas? I always though **init** was probably magical but now that I dig into it, I can't find anything that lets me provide myself this really simple convenience.

Comment: Have you tried putting `from user import User` into the `__init__.py` under the `models/` directory?

Comment: Yeah, the problem with that is those circular references. Lemme update my question to clarify.

Comment: Did you manage to import either `User` or `Banana` at all, or is it failing due to the cyclic import anyway?

Comment: The circular imports are the real problem here. Until you solve those, neither `user` nor `banana` will work properly. `__init__` does no magic. See https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-can-i-have-modules-that-mutually-import-each-other

Comment: Dang. Thanks for the link, very helpful. This bums me. Certainly not an easy problem, but php never made me think about this junk. Class autoloaders ftw I guess. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024455/perls-autoload-in-python-getattr-on-a-module hmm maybe there's an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your circular references are for. If you have a class in user that inherits from Banana and a class in banana that inherits from User, you can't do this. You also can't do it if each class defines a decorator that gets used in the other or anything else that gets called during the actual import.

You can, however, if you are just mutually referencing helper functions, or if your User object has a method to create new instances of Banana and your Banana object has a method that creates new instances of User. As long as the mutual reference doesn't actually get used until something in the module is called from outside it, then in your model folder, in `__init__.py`, you can just do something like:

```
import user
import banana
#etc...
user.banana = banana
banana.user = user
#etc...

User = user.User
Banana = banana.Banana
```

Then for sake of clarity and not trying to figure out what's going on

Comment: That looks promising. I'll see if that does it for me.