# Raise custom ImportError when user imports a deprecated variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have written a package where a sub-module contains a module-level variable `deprecated_var` that I want to remove, because it was a horrible mistake.

```
mypkg
  - mymodule
    - __init__.py
```

But instead of just leaving my end users with a generic `ImportError`, I want to print a message that says their import is deprecated, and what they should do. So instead of:

```
>>> from mypkg.mymodule import deprecated_var
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'deprecated_var'
```

I want users to see something like this:

```
>>> from mypkg.mymodule import deprecated_var
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: mypkg.mymodule.deprecated_var was removed. Replace 
  with "from foo.bar import Baz; deprecated_var = Baz()"
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Can't you just `raise ImportError("that's deprecated")`? i.e. Just construct an `ImportError` with a custom string message.

Comment: @9769953: I agree and personally like Alex Martelli's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/922645/355230) (even if he thinks it might be overkill).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible before python 3.7.

However, in python 3.7 or later, this can be achieved by using the module level `__getattr__` added in [PEP562](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0562/).

You'd use like so:

```
#_deprecated_vars is a dict of keys -> alternatives (or None)
_deprecated_vars: Dict[str, Optional[str]] = {
        'deprecated_var': 'from foo.bar import Baz; deprecated_var = Baz()', 
        'other_deprecated_var': None
    }

def __getattr__(name):
    if name in _deprecated_vars:
        alt_text = '{name} was removed from module {__name__}'
        replace_text = _deprecated_vars[name]
        if replace_text is not None:
           alt_text += f'. Replace with {replace_text!r}.'
        raise AttributeError(alt_text)
    raise AttributeError(f"module {__name__} has no attribute {name}")
```

---

However, I'm not sure this works for your use case of `from a.b import deprecated_var`. This is more for `import a.b; a.b.deprecated_var`. See the other answer for the former.

Answer (score 2):

For your specific example, you could use the following:

`mymodule/__init__.py`:

```
#deprecated_var = 5
replacement_var = 6
```

`mymodule/deprecated_var.py`:

```
raise ImportError("deprecated_var is deprecated. Use mypkg.mymodule.replacement_var instead")
```

While this raises the custom `ImportError` when importing the variable directly:

```
>>> from mymodule import deprecated_var
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".../mymodule/deprecated_var.py", line 1, in <module>
    raise ImportError("deprecated_var is deprecated. Use mypkg.mymodule.replacement_var instead")
ImportError: deprecated_var is deprecated. Use mypkg.mymodule.replacement_var instead
```

it does nothing when accessing it as a module attribute. Or rather, it throws an `AttributeError` instead of a deprecation warning:

```
>>> import mymodule
>>> mymodule.deprecated_var
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'mymodule' has no attribute 'deprecated_var'
```