# Callable modules

Tags: python, module, python-import

Why doesn't Python allow modules to have a [`__call__`](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) method? (Beyond the obvious that it wouldn't be easy to import directly.) Specifically, why doesn't using `a(b)` syntax find the `__call__` attribute like it does for functions, classes, and objects? (Is lookup just incompatibly different for modules?)

```
>>> print(open("mod_call.py").read())
def __call__():
    return 42

>>> import mod_call
>>> mod_call()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
>>> mod_call.__call__()
42
```

Comment: Migrating a decorator from a package into its own sub-module. @example(...) was by far still the most common use-case, but @example.special_case(...) was a new use. I didn't want to implement it with an example class and static methods, since that was a poor fit. Not sure a callable module is a better fit, but I started investigating it and then wanted to know why it didn't work.

Comment: I had also thought it could simplify some modules such as datetime and decimal, by making the module.__call__ be datetime.datetime or decimal.Decimal respectively. However, then type(decimal('1')) wouldn't be the same as decimal, and possible other issues. *shrug* It was an idea.

Comment: "Beyond the obvious that it wouldn't be easy to import directly." Why do you think that?

Comment: @Longpoke: It would be cumbersome and inconsistent to import just *__call__*.  Perhaps I could've phrased that better (when I asked this over a year ago), but it still appears that way to me.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, like `from mymodule import __call__` ?

Comment: @Longpoke: Yes, that's what I meant by "import just *__call__*".

Comment: Warning: this trick will make your code not working with tools like Pylint. Everything fails. I guess typing more characters at the end save the time in this case: see libraries like tqdm whose are primarily called with `from tqdm import tqdm` but they didn't apply this trick.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Special methods are only guaranteed to be called implicitly when they are defined on the type, not on the instance.  (`__call__` is an attribute of the module instance `mod_call`, not of `<type 'module'>`.)  You can't add methods to built-in types.

https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-lookup

Comment: Package `forbiddenfruit` begs to differ about being able to add special methods onto builtin types, but I mention this only as an academic curiosity. I think there are only relatively rare cases where monkeypatching builtin types is acceptable, and it would be particularly bad for a typical imported module to do so. (Incidentally, `forbiddenfruit` cannot monkeypatch `object`, and it can cause segfaults later in execution if you try, but it _can_ monkeypatch `<type 'function'>`, so I'm assuming it can probably monkeypatch `<type 'module'>` but I wouldn't bet my life on it.)

Answer (score 110):

Python doesn't allow modules to override or add *any* magic method, because keeping module objects simple, regular and lightweight is just too advantageous considering how rarely strong use cases appear where you could use magic methods there.

When such use cases *do* appear, the solution is to make a class instance masquerade as a module. Specifically, code your `mod_call.py` as follows:

```
import sys

class mod_call:
    def __call__(self):
        return 42

sys.modules[__name__] = mod_call()
```

Now your code importing and calling `mod_call` works fine.

Comment: Wow. I was seconds from posting a code example based on this example of yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880530/can-python-modules-have-properties-the-same-way-that-objects-can/880550#880550

Comment: Note: instead of the class with a \_\_call\_\_ method, a normal function is also possible

Comment: Note: This solution does hide other functions (or other items) in the module. This can be _solved_ by adding them to class

Comment: You may want to subclass `types.ModuleType` so that it is still considered a module object.  (then you really would have a callable module)

Comment: I like @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen 's suggestion of subclassing `ModuleType` but be aware that if you do, you'll need to override `__init__` to pass in the name of the module to `super().__init__('moduleName')`

Comment: @MichaelScottCuthbert or equivalently replace `sys.modules[__name__] = mod_call()` with `sys.modules[__name__] = mod_call(__name__)`

Comment: This works for `import mod_call`, but for `from mod_call import *; mod_call()` I get `NameError: name 'mod_call' is not defined`. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: @Friedrich I guess none.

Comment: @Friedrich Put `mod_call` as an attribute named `mod_call` on itself. `mod_call.mod_call = mod_call` below the end of the `class mod_call` definition. You also need to define `__all__ = ["mod_call"]` or equivalent in `class mod_call`.

Comment: @mtraceur Thx. This is basically what I suggested below in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61618555/11769765.

Comment: @Friedrich Cheers, I didn't scroll very far in the answers. Just saw your comment here and felt like improvising a solution. Glad to see you had figured it out much sooner.

Answer (score 23):

As Miles says, you need to define the call on class level.
So an alternative to Alex post is to change the class of `sys.modules[__name__]` to a subclass of the type of `sys.modules[__name__]` (It should be `types.ModuleType`).

This has the advantage that the module is callable while keeping all other properties of the module (like accessing functions, variables, ...).

```py
import sys

class MyModule(sys.modules[__name__].__class__):
    def __call__(self):  # module callable
        return 42

sys.modules[__name__].__class__ = MyModule
```

Note: Tested with python3.6.

Comment: This only works on Python 3.5 and up, because it relies on a [special case](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.5.0/Objects/typeobject.c#L3669) added in 3.5 that singles out modules as the only objects implemented in C that can have their `__class__` reassigned.

Comment: For later readers: don't forget to inherit `sys.modules[__name__].__class__` since: `TypeError: __class__ assignment only supported for heap types or ModuleType subclasses..`

Answer (score 10):

[Christoph Böddeker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48100440/2132213) seems to be the best way to create a callable module, but as [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060796/callable-modules#comment89750075_48100440) says, it only works in Python 3.5 and up.

The benefit is that you can write your module like normal, and just add the class reassignment at the very end, i.e.

```
# coolmodule.py
import stuff

var = 33
class MyClass:
   ...
def function(x, y):
   ...

class CoolModule(types.ModuleType):
    def __call__(self):
        return 42
sys.modules[__name__].__class__ = CoolModule
```

and everything works, including all expected module attributes like `__file__` being defined. (This is because you're actually not changing the module object resulting from the import at all, just "casting" it to a subclass with a `__call__` method, which is exactly what we want.)

To get this to work similarly in Python versions below 3.5, you can adapt [Alex Martelli's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1060872/2132213) to make your new class a subclass of ModuleType, and copy all the module's attributes into your new module instance:

```
#(all your module stuff here)

class CoolModule(types.ModuleType):
    def __init__(self):
        types.ModuleType.__init__(self, __name__)
        # or super().__init__(__name__) for Python 3
        self.__dict__.update(sys.modules[__name__].__dict__)
    def __call__(self):
        return 42

sys.modules[__name__] = CoolModule()
```

Now `__file__`, `__name__` and other module attributes are defined (which aren't present if just following Alex's answer), and your imported module object still "is a" module.

Answer (score 6):

All answers work only for `import mod_call`. To get it working simultaneously for `from mod_call import *`, the solution of @Alex Martelli can be enhanced as follow

```
import sys

class mod_call:
    def __call__(self):
        return 42
    mod_call = __call__
    __all__ = list(set(vars().keys()) - {'__qualname__'})   # for python 2 and 3

sys.modules[__name__] = mod_call()
```

This solution was derived with the discussion of an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7668273/11769765) of a similar problem.

Comment: The no-maintenance/no-duplication `__all__` is a cool addition! Personally, I would filter out anything that starts with an `_` from `__all__`, and I would also make `__all__` a tuple. Something like `__all__ = tuple(key for key in vars() if not key.startswith('_'))`.

Answer (score 2):

To turn the solution into a convenient reusable function:

```py
def set_module(cls, __name__):
    import sys

    class cls2(sys.modules[__name__].__class__, cls):
        pass

    sys.modules[__name__].__class__ = cls2
```

save it to, say, `util.py`. Then in your module,

```py
import util

class MyModule:
    def __call__(self):  # module callable
        return 42

util.set_module(MyModule, __name__)
```

Hurray!

I wrote this because I need to enhance a lot of modules with this trick.

---

P.S. Few days after I wrote this answer, I removed this trick from my code, since it is so tricky for tools like Pylint to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Using Python version 3.10.8, formatting my code as below allowed me to:

- Make my module callable ([thanks Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1060872/2807702))
- Keep all properties of the module accessible (e.g. methods) ([thanks Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55170086/2807702))
- Allow the module to work when used as `from CallableModule import x, y, z`, although not as `from CallableModule import *` (I tried to employ [Friedrich's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61618555/2807702))

```py
    from types import ModuleType
    
    class CallableModule(ModuleType):
        def __init__(self):
            ModuleType.__init__(self, __name__)
            self.__dict__.update(modules[__name__].__dict__)
    
        def __call__(self):
            print("You just called a module UwU")
      
        mod_call= __call__
        __all__= list(set(vars().keys()) - {'__qualname__'})
    modules[__name__]= CallableModule()
```