# Can a python module have a __repr__?

Tags: python, module

Can a python module have a __repr__? The idea would be to do something like:

```
import mymodule
print mymodule
```

EDIT: precision: I mean a **user-defined** repr!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Short answer**: basically the answer is no.

But can't you find the functionality you are looking for using docstrings?

```
testmodule.py
```

```
""" my module test does x and y
"""
class myclass(object):
    ...
```

```
test.py
```

```
import testmodule
print testmodule.__doc__
```

**Long answer:**

You can define your own `__repr__` on a module level (just provide `def __repr__(...`) but then you'd have to do:

```
import mymodule
print mymodule.__repr__()
```

to get the functionality you want.

Have a look at the following python shell session:

```
>>> import sys                 # we import the module
>>> sys.__repr__()               # works as usual
"<module 'sys' (built-in)>"
>>> sys.__dict__['__repr__']     # but it's not in the modules __dict__ ?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: '__repr__'
>>> sys.__class__.__dict__['__repr__'] # __repr__ is provided on the module type as a slot wrapper
<slot wrapper '__repr__' of 'module' objects>
>>> sys.__class__.__dict__['__repr__'](sys) # which we should feed an instance of the module type
"<module 'sys' (built-in)>"
```

So I believe the problem lies within these [slot wrapper objects](http://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/python/SlotWrapperObjects) which (from what can be read at the link) have the result of bypassing the usual 'python' way of looking up item attributes.

For these class methods CPython returns C pointers to the corresponding methods on these objects (which then get wrapped in the slot wrapper objects to be callable from the python-side).

Comment: I'd be interested in hearing Alex Martelli's explanation ;-)

Comment: Christophe: I'll save you the trouble, as he told me why, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060796/callable-modules and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725515/can-a-python-module-have-a-repr/1725968#1725968.

Answer (score 9):

You can achieve this effect--*if* you're willing to turn to the Dark Side of the Force.

Add this to **mymodule.py:**

```
import sys

class MyReprModule(mymodule.__class__):
  def __init__(self, other):
    for attr in dir(other):
      setattr(self, attr, getattr(other, attr))

  def __repr__(self):
    return 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOQ'

# THIS LINE MUST BE THE LAST LINE IN YOUR MODULE
sys.modules[__name__] = MyReprModule(sys.modules[__name__])
```

Lo and behold:

```
>>> import mymodule
>>> print mymodule
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOQ
```

I dimly remember, in previous attempts at similarly evil hacks, having trouble setting special attributes like `__class__`.  I didn't have that trouble when testing this.  If you run into that problem, just catch the exception and skip that attribute.

Comment: This is the best answer, shame that it's not ranked higher. Also, it's not really an "evil" hack IMHO: the only value you're changing at the sys level is the name of the module itself. I feel that the owner of a module should be able to safely tweak anything related to that module.

Answer (score 6):

Modules can have a `__repr__` function, but it isn't invoked when getting the representation of a module.

So no, you can't do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

As a matter of fact, many modules do [have a `__repr__`]!

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys)
<module 'sys' (built-in)>    #read edit, however, this info didn't come from __repr__ !
```

also try `dir(sys)` to see `__repr__` is there along with `__name__` etc..

**Edit**:
`__repr__` seems to be found in modules, in Python 3.0 and up.
As indicated by Ned Batchelder, this methods is *not* used by Python when it print out the a module. (A quick experiment, where the **repr** property was re-assigned showed that...)

Comment: __repr__ is not in my sys attributes (python 2.6.2)

Comment: For what it's worth, I found `sys.__repr__` in my Python (2.5.1), but I do think that it's not what gets printed out with `print(sys)`.

Comment: In python 2.6.2 `__repr__` is not in `dir(sys)` or `sys.__dict__`. However, it is a valid key in `sys.__class__.__dict__' (`<slot wrapper '__repr__' of 'module' objects>`).

Answer (score 1):

No, because `__repr__` is a special method (I call it a *capability*), and it is only ever looked up on the class. Your module is just another instance of the module type, so however you would manage to define a `__repr__`, it would not be called!