# in Python, how to overwrite the str for a module?

Tags: python, string, overwrite

When one types the name of a module and then hits return, one gets a string
like below

```
import pandas as pd
pd

<module 'pandas' from '....'>
```

How can I overwrite this string for my own module ?
(Please note that I am referring to a module, not to a class)
For example adding a text below like

```
<module 'mymodule' from '....'>
my additional custom text
```

I tried to add this to mymodule:

```
def __str__():
   print('my additional custom text')
```

and also

```
def __str__():
   return 'my additional custom text'

def __repr__():
    print("my additional custom text")
    return "my additional custom text"
```

but nothing happens

Of course, if I type

```
mymodule.__str__()
```

I get 'my additional custom text'

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/python-str-repr-functions ?

but the main thing is probably to use return instead of print

Comment: I would start with looking at `__name__` and `__spec__` and particularly `__str__`

Comment: Did you also dig into `__repr__` instead of  `__str__`  ?  Depending from where you are typing those python commands, it may be the right redefinition to do.

Comment: Possible relevant, though I think this was from the Python 2 days: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725515/can-a-python-module-have-a-repr

Comment: What ***do*** you get when you just type `mymodule`?

Comment: @KellyBundy I get: <module 'mymodule' from '....'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JonSG was correct, it reads it from `__spec__` - I found all the logic for it is in the [importlib._bootstrap](https://pykaldi.github.io/_modules/importlib/_bootstrap.html) module.

This is how you'd modify the module name and path:

```
import sys

if __spec__ is not None:
    file_path = 'C:/other_file'
    name = 'new_name'

    __spec__.origin = file_path

    if name != __spec__.name:
        sys.modules[name] = sys.modules[__spec__.name]
        __spec__.name = name
```

When I import the file:

```
<module 'new_name' from 'C:/other_file'>
```

Changing the name actually requires editing `sys.modules` so be careful. Changing the path however looks completely fine.

Comment: What can be done is to leave the real path name, and append a string to it. I had actually hoped it was something less invasive to do. Thanks to everyone that helped clarify the issue

Answer (score 1):

A short answer is: cannot do. `Importlib` puts the module's `repr` together with its `name` and `origin` properties. Check out the [`_module_repr_from_spec`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4307feaddc76b9e93cd38e325a1f0ee59d593093/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py#L735) function implementation.

I believe subclassing [ModuleSpec](https://peps.python.org/pep-0451/#modulespec) and overriding its attributes is also not a viable option, unless you decide to do without `Importlib` and somehow load modules by yourself.