# get all methods defined in my own module

Tags: python, python-3.x

say I have a module like so:

```
def print_hello(name):
  " prints a greeting "
  print("Hello, {}!".format(name.title()))
```

I want to set a sys.settrace on my module, so whenever a function *from my module is called*, it prints a block to stdout, like so

```
CALLED FUNCTION: say_hello()
Hello, Alex!
```

Predictably, the trace method will pick up ALL methods which are called, which results in this:

```
$ python3 trace_example.py
Called function: print_hello
Hello, Alex!
Called function: _remove
```

How can I tell if a method is in the current module?

(here is my trace function if you were wondering:)

```
import sys
def tracefunc(frame, event, args):
  if event == 'call':
    print("Called function: {}()".format(frame.f_code.co_name))
sys.settrace(tracefunc)
```

Comment: Maybe this, using ```inspect``` - [Retrieve module object from stack frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000861/retrieve-module-object-from-stack-frame)

Comment: That helps, but still has the problem of the following:
 
print(dir(this_module))
`['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'inspect', 'print_hello', 'sys', 'tracefunc']`

Ideally it'd only have `print_hello` and `tracefunc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the module name of a frame object with:

```
frame.f_globals['__name__']
```

Or if you want to check the previous call in the frame stack, (I'm not sure which one is more interesting right now):

```
frame.f_back.f_globals['__name__']
```

Of course, note that `f_back` may be `None` and that the global dictionary may not have a `__name__` member.

**UPDATE:**
If you have a module object and want to list all the top-level callable objects:

```
callables = [n for n,f in module.__dict__.items() if hasattr(f, '__call__')]
```

That will get also the types, because technically they look a bit like functions, but you can refine the condition further if you want. (See this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624926/how-to-detect-whether-a-python-variable-is-a-function) for extra details.

Comment: that will give the name of the module, but then from that, how would I extract the methods within that module?

Comment: Your question is _How can I tell if a method is in the current module?_ but the title is _get all methods defined in my own module_. Those are two different questions... which one do you need?

Comment: I need all methods that belong to the current module being called. So this looks pretty close to it, but then I think there needs to be some kind of list comprehension to extract all methods not in builtins. So the end result would look something like: `['print_hello']` in this case, because I only defined one method in module