# Why do imports not work when creating custom module classes?

Tags: python, module

I have this module, `wat.py`

```
import re
import types
import sys

hello = "Hello World"

class MyModule(types.ModuleType):
    def get_re(self):
        return re
    def get_hello(self):
        return hello


sys.modules[__name__] = MyModule('wat')
```

And I run this code:

```
>>> import wat
>>> wat.get_hello()
None
>>> wat.get_re()
None
```

Why does this not work?

Comment: If I were you, I would start with a more general python tutorial... (http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

Comment: @gecco: I'm not new to python. I'm trying to make a module callable, but the imports are going awry.

Comment: ok, sorry, I got something wrong...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060796/callable-modules

Comment: @root: I was looking at that to begin with, but found it didn't play well with imports

Comment: If you set a breakpoint with `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` in the `get_hello()` method and inspect the locals and globals, you'll notice that `hello` is `None` (it's defined though). I'm not exactly sure why this is happening, but that seems to be the root cause of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you effectively deleted your module when you reassigned its entry in `sys.modules`. See my related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365562/why-is-the-value-of-name-changing-after-assignment-to-sys-modules-name).

To make it work, change the last line of your module to:

```
_ref, sys.modules[__name__] = sys.modules[__name__], MyModule('wat')
```

and it will work.

BTW, you don't have to derive your class from `types.ModuleType` in order to put instances of it in `sys.modules[]`. Entries in `sys.modules` don't have to be module objects (according to [Alex Martelli](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65207-constants-in-python/)).

Comment: _"you don't have to derive your class from `types.ModuleType`"_ - true, but I see no reason not to.

Comment: @Eric: Depends on what your class is or does, as in is it a type (or subclass) of a module, or is it something else altogether.

Answer (score 1):

This code makes it work:

```
import types
import sys

def whyDoesThisWorkIDontEven():
    import re
    hello = "Hello World"

    class MyModule(types.ModuleType):
        def get_re(self):
            return re
        def get_hello(self):
            return hello

    return MyModule('wat')

sys.modules[__name__] = whyDoesThisWorkIDontEven()
```

But I have *absolutely no idea* why.

Comment: I think this makes it work because Python sets all the variables to `None` in a module when it's deleted as stated in the accepted answer to the linked question in my answer. Actually it would be more accurately to say it (only) sets all the top-level module attributes in its `__dict__` to `None` -- so what you've done here effectively protects things by moving them down a level to inside the function. This makes it work but doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by "doesn't play well with imports" as this seems to work also. Not sure if thats what you want but maybe it's useful...

```
    import sys
    import re
    class _Test(object):
      def __init__(self):
          self.re=re
      def testfunc(self):
          return self.re
      y = property(testfunc)
    sys.modules[__name__] = _Test()

import calltest

>>> calltest.y
<module 're' from 'C:\Python26\lib\re.pyc'>
>>> calltest.re
<module 're' from 'C:\Python26\lib\re.pyc'>
>>> calltest.testfunc()
<module 're' from 'C:\Python26\lib\re.pyc'>
```

EDIT:

If you simply try to `return re` you will get `None`. You have to import `re` after you do

```
sys.modules[__name__] = _Test()
```

like:

```
sys.modules[__name__] = _Test()
import re
```

then simply calling re woudld work.

Comment: Have an upvote for a working solution. But why is `re` in scope in `__init__`, but not in `testfunc`?