# Can I make a Python Module __init__.py callable?

Tags: python

The documentation for `__init__.py` is quite hard to find. I can't find a place that explains all the things you can do in this file. The Python module documentation barely even mentions `__init__.py` nor that you can use `__all__` for `from module import *`

What I want is for my module to be callable like:

main.py

```
import module

module()
```

module/__ init __.py

```
def __call__(self):    # self here cause modules are loaded as objects?
    print 'callable'
```

Comment: Hmmm, you're treating a module like a package?

Comment: basically i just dont want a ton of pyc files in my main folder or to do things like import module.module :p

Comment: Here's your doc for `__init__.py`: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: I don't think there is any way to make a module callable.

Comment: This is what Python says when you try to call a module: `'module' object is not callable`. This means that anything that is a `'module'` _cannot be called_ in any circumstances.

Comment: but if i write a class without a `__call__` override it also throws `'class' object is not callable` so i assumed they follow the same logic since they errors are identical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe silly answer but you can add method into `__init__.py` file like

**__init__.py**

```
def module():
    # what functions do you need to run into __init__ file
```

and then

**main.py**

```
from module import module
module()
```

also, you just can write some operations into **init** and then it will be calling after import

example:

**__init__.py**

```
print('1')
print('2')
print('3')
```

**main.py**

```
import module
```

after run **main.py**
the output will be

```
1
2
3
```

---

but actually, it's not good practice. Try to write code without "calling" modules because a module is a file containing Python definitions and statements, not the function that needs to call.

Comment: yea thanks i am aware of this, there plenty of functions in my `module`, but for esthetic purposes i wanted my module to be callable like a bunch of other objects my code deal with

Comment: did you see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060796/callable-modules)
maybe will be useful for you.

Comment: OH MY BOY, you mah boy artem, thanks so much. wish i have enough rep to give you an up too <3