# Callable modules with parameters

Tags: python, module

Is it possible to make a module callable with parameters?

I am trying to make a callable module on Python, following the question and its answers [Callable modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060796/callable-modules), like so:

> *foo.py*

```
import sys

class foo(object):
  def __call__(self):
    return 'callable'

sys.modules[__name__] = foo()
```

then I call it:

```
import foo

print(foo()) # 'callable'
```

but my objective is to pass a parameter in the callable module:

`print(foo('parameter'))`

Any ideas how can I accomplish that?

Comment: You didn't define `__call__` with any parameters.

Comment: Yes, I tried but when I add more parameters other than self it give me an error

Comment: Show us that code, and the error message.

Comment: I add this parameter like so:
`def __call__(a, self):
    return a`
 and when I called `print(sta('a'))` it didn't give me an error, it give me `<sta.foo object at 0x10faee6a0>`

Comment: @user10287754 You have to put `self` first, and any additional parameters after that.

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/WearableWeakCareware

Comment: Thank you, I guess it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing special about the class you created (it's not even a `ModuleType` subclass), so there's nothing special about its [`__call__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) method. If you want to call it with arguments, just add parameters to the `__call__` definition:

```
import sys

class foo(object):
  def __call__(self, x):
    return f'callable, and called with {x}'

sys.modules[__name__] = foo()
```

And now, you can pass it an argument, exactly like any other callable object:

```
import foo

print(foo('hello'))
```

And [the output is](https://repl.it/repls/WearableWeakCareware):

```
callable, and called with hello
```

---

From the comments, you tried to do this:

```
def __call__(a, self):
    return a
```

But, like all methods in Python, `__call__` wants `self` to come first. It doesn't care about the names (unless you call it with keyword arguments), just the order: the first parameter gets the receiver (the `foo` in `foo('hello')`), even if it you called that parameter `a`, and the second parameter gets the first normal argument (the `'hello'`), even if you called that parameter `self`.

So, you're passing the module `foo` as the first parameter, `a`, and you `return a`, so it returns `foo`.

Which is why you got this:

```
<sta.foo object at 0x10faee6a0>
```

That isn't an error, that's the perfectly valid output that you get when you print out an instance of a class that doesn't define `__repr__` or `__str__`.

Comment: This does not always work though sadly. If you do from foo import * then foo('test') will throw an error, 'foo is not defined'.