# How to pass arguments to __init__.py?

Tags: python-3.x, package, parameter-passing, init, namespace-package

Considering a namespace package in python 3.7, how would I pass an argument to my package when I initialise it?

```
my_package
  __init__.py
```

I wish to be able to call `my_package(arg)`.

Thank you,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Callable modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060796/callable-modules)

Comment: @blueteeth so should I just add "def__call__(arg)"  to my__init__.py?

Comment: No. This answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48100440/1904146 It won't work in an interpreter either, only when called from a file.