# short import paths in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, import

I'm coming back to python and having trouble with import paths. Can someone explain the logic, or a better way of doing this?
If I have a class called `Sentence` in structure like

```
base.py
models/Sentence.py
```

then inside `base.py`

```
import models.Sentence
```

why do I still have to do

```
s = models.Sentence.Sentence('arg')
```

I can't seem to fix it on import either

```
import models.Sentence as Sentence # ok but no help
import models.Sentence.Sentence as Sentence  # illegal and weird
```

I realize there's some magic I can do within the `__init__` module file, but that seems like a magic hack.

It seems very odd to have to refer to the whole filepath each time I create a class instance so I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong. JS' explicit export and imports seem much clearer.

Comment: Have you tried `from models.Sentence import Sentence`?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `import models.Sentence`, you're telling Python to load your `Sentence.py` file, and put all of its variables inside the `models.Sentence` namespace. Thus, your `Sentence` class also becomes listed under `models.Sentence`, and so it becomes `models.Sentence.Sentence`.

In terms of using `__init__.py`, you can put something like this in that file:

```
from .Sentence import * # or import Sentence if that's all you want
```

and then in your `base.py`:

```
import models

my_sentence = models.Sentence("arg")
```

What your `__init__.py` does now is load everything from `Sentence.py` into its own namespace, instead of `models.Sentence`. So that means your `Sentence` class is no longer `models.Sentence.Sentence`, and is now just `models.Sentence`.

NB: If you want to be able to run your `__init__.py` file as the main file, or run any script inside the `models` folder, you should put this code in `__init__.py` instead:

```
import __main__, os

if os.path.dirname(__main__.__file__) == os.path.dirname(__file__):
    # executed script in this folder
    from Sentence import *
else:
    # executed script from elsewhere
    from .Sentence import *
```

**EDIT:**

To understand why you need to use `models.Sentence.Sentence('arg')`, let's look at a clearer example:

Suppose I have a module I've made called `package`. In that module, I have sub-module `this_useful_part.py`.

This is the folder structure:

```
main.py
package
    this_useful_part.py
```

In `this_useful_part.py`:

```
class my_very_helpful_class:
    pass
```

In `main.py`:

```
import package.this_useful_part

my_instance = package.this_useful_part.my_very_helpful_class()
```

(I realise I may not have chosen the best names)

The reason I require `package.this_useful_part.my_very_helpful_class`, and you require `models.Sentence.Sentence` is because the class is **not** the file, but stored within the file, and the file is **not** the folder, but stored within the folder.

The ways around this:

- You can put the class definition inside `__init__.py`, so when you import `models`, it can be referenced as `models.Sentence`.
- You do as I did above, where you import everything from `Sentence.py`, so that the class definition is also stored directly inside the `__init__.py` file, and so it can be referenced as `models.Sentence`.

I hope this clears things up.

**EDIT 2:**

After a bit more research, I found that it is possible to make a module callable. (From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060796/callable-modules))

You don't require an `__init__.py` file if you change the code in your `Sentence.py` file to this:

```
import sys

class Sentence:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg

sys.modules[__name__] = Sentence
```

You can now do

```
import models.Sentence

my_sentence = models.Sentence('arg')
```

Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: thanks but `import models` would surely import ALL models any time one model is used? Doesn't seem on point. Also resorting to overriding exports in an `__init__ ` file just feels like a hack. Is there really no way to refer to a class by it's classname without this stuff? Also `.Sentence` filename with a path in it ;;(

Comment: What would you like to be able to do? Basically, variables have to be organised into namespaces, so the only ways of calling `models.Sentence('arg')` is to do one of the things above to create a reference to the `Sentence` class inside `__init__.py`.

Comment: usually I keep one class per file, so this just adds a lot of redundancy to imports. I want to import the class, not the full path to that. So your example: `my_instance = package.useful_part.helpful_class()` would actually be `inst = package.class.class(opts)` ie duplicative. But from your addendum we can somehow patch `sys.modules` to add a (duplicate) short circuit reference. Two wrongs don't make a right...

Comment: what the `sys.modules[__name__]` line does is reassigns the reference to the module to your class. Therefore, when you try to call the module (which is not normally allowed), you are instead calling your class...

Answer (score 0):

I think that the python documentation explains it quite well and that I can not do a better job, so I'll just quote and provide you the links.

---

[Python documentation on packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) *(This is just the portion relevant to this question, but I strongly encourage you to open the link and read it from there.)*:

> Users of the package can import individual modules from the package,
>   for example:
>
> ```
> import sound.effects.echo
> ```
>
> This loads the submodule sound.effects.echo. It must be referenced
>   with its full name.
>
> ```
> sound.effects.echo.echofilter(input, output, delay=0.7, atten=4)
> ```
>
> An alternative way of importing the submodule is:
>
> ```
> from sound.effects import echo
> ```
>
> This also loads the submodule echo, and makes it available without its
>   package prefix, so it can be used as follows:
>
> ```
> echo.echofilter(input, output, delay=0.7, atten=4)
> ```
>
> Yet another variation is to import the desired function or variable
>   directly:
>
> ```
> from sound.effects.echo import echofilter
> ```
>
> Again, this loads the submodule echo, but this makes its function
>   echofilter() directly available:
>
> ```
> echofilter(input, output, delay=0.7, atten=4)
> ```

---

[Documentation about the import statement](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/simple_stmts.html#import) *(Again, I encourage you to open the link and read from there.)*:

> The basic import statement (no from clause) is executed in two steps:
>
> 1. find a module, loading and initializing it if necessary
> 2. define a name or names in the local namespace for the scope where
>      the import statement occurs.
>
> [...]
>
> If the requested module is retrieved successfully, it will be made
>   available in the local namespace in one of three ways:
>
> - If the module name is followed by `as`, then the name following `as` is    bound directly to the imported module.
> - If no other name is specified, and the module being imported is a top    level module, the module’s name is bound in the local namespace
>     as a    reference to the imported module
> - If the module being imported is not a top level module, then the name    of the top level package that contains the module is bound in
>     the    local namespace as a reference to the top level package. The
>     imported    module must be accessed using its full qualified name
>     rather than    directly
>
> The `from` form uses a slightly more complex process:
>
> 1. find the module specified in the `from` clause, loading and
>      initializing it if necessary;
> 2. for each of the identifiers specified in the `import` clauses:
>
>    1. check if the imported module has an attribute by that name
>    2. if not, attempt to import a submodule with that name and then check the imported module again for that attribute
>    3. if the attribute is not found, `ImportError` is raised.
>    4. otherwise, a reference to that value is stored in the local namespace, using the name in the `as` clause if it is present,
>         otherwise using the attribute name
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> import foo                 # foo imported and bound locally
> import foo.bar.baz         # foo.bar.baz imported, foo bound locally
> import foo.bar.baz as fbb  # foo.bar.baz imported and bound as fbb
> from foo.bar import baz    # foo.bar.baz imported and bound as baz
> from foo import attr       # foo imported and foo.attr bound as attr
> ```

---

And finally, for more details you can read [the import system](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/import.html#importsystem).

Comment: Welcome to SO! Yes, I read the docs but that is what lead me to the current mess I have. I assumed it was my error but it just seems the python way is just ... a bit uncomfortable. I guess you just learn that's the way it is and get used to it.