# Make a Python module's name its root class instantiated

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, module

I have a module with the structure:

```
- mymodule
  - mymodule
      __init__.py
      core.py
  setup.py
```

`__init__.py` contents:

```
from .core import MyClass
```

So now when I import my module I have to do:

```
import mymodule

mymodule.MyClass()
```

but what I want is:

```
import mymodule

MyModule()
```

but I don't want to have to:

```
from mymodule import MyModule
```

Can this be done and if so how?

Comment: Why on earth wouldn't you want to use the `from` keyword? If it's not just laziness, this definitely needs more context.

Comment: There are some hacks, check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060796/callable-modules. But why don't you want to explicitly import the stuff you need?

Comment: No, it cannot. That is simply not how python imports work vis a vis namespaces

Comment: what if in the __init__() I instantiate the MyModule class and return it?

Comment: @xendi What are you trying to accomplish here? This isn't Ruby or C/C++ you can't just import all functions, classes, etc sanely into a module without the from keyword.

Comment: Just thinking of how to make it easier for the user

Comment: Who is the user? If they're a python programmer they should understand how the `from` keyword works. You're getting too far ahead of yourself here.

Comment: alright then, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest you can get is star import:

```
from mymodule import *
```

Comment: This is the correct answer unless you plan on using `exec` to dynamically inject modules into the module, which is f**king nasty but I should note can be done.