# Can a module be callable in python?

Tags: python

Probably this is an stupid question, but.... I've come across the python error "module is not callable" and I was wondering if we could make a module to be callable.

In other words, something like this:

```
import my_module 

# here an error "module is not callable" would 
# appear here, but the question is whether the 
# module can be changed in order to make the 
# module callable
my_module()
```

And works, without modification. Can we make some arrangements in a python module to make it callable???

Comment: Can you share what you are trying to import as a module?

Comment: Yes, if `module.__call__` were defined. It's not, which is why you get the error.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060796/callable-modules

Comment: @overflow95 thanks!