# How to lazily evaluate ORM call after fixtures are loaded into db in Django?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, lazy-loading, fixtures

I've got a module `pagetypes.py` that extracts a couple of constants (I shouldn't really use word constant here) from the db for later reuse:

```
def _get_page_type_(type):
    return PageType.objects.get(type=type)

PAGE_TYPE_MAIN = _get_page_type_('Main')
PAGE_TYPE_OTHER = _get_page_type_('Other')
```

then somewhere in views I do:

```
import pagetypes
...
print pagetypes.PAGE_TYPE_MAIN #simplified
```

It all works fine when db has those records and I make sure it does... unless this code is under test. In that case I want to load those records into db via fixtures. The problem with that is that fixtures are not loaded (even `syncdb` is not run) by the time pagetypes module is imported resulting in `_get_page_type_` call failing with:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "pagetype" does not exist
```

Test runner always tries to import `pagetypes` module, because it is imported by view that is under test.

How do I get around this problem?

I was thinking of lazily loading pagetype constants `PAGE_TYPE_MAIN`, `PAGE_TYPE_OTHER`, but then I want it to fail early if those records are not in the db (or fixtures if under test), so I don't really know how to implement this.

I was also thinking of object level caching and just call `PageType.objects.get(type=type)` whenever constant is used/called, but wouldn't that be an overkill? Calling orm without cache would result in too many db calls, which I want to prevent.

It must be something very simple, but I can't work it out. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the functions instead of the constants, but memoize them:

```
_cache = {}

def get_page_type(type_name):
    if type_name not in _cache:
        _cache[type_name] = PageType.objects.get(type=type_name)
    return _cache[type_name]
```

So now you'd call `get_page_type('Main')` directly when necessary.

Comment: That's pretty clever and simple.

Comment: I've slightly modified your code to do less typing every time I want to use page type constant:

`PAGE_TYPE_MAIN = property(lambda: get_page_type('Main'))`

I used some code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880530/can-python-modules-have-properties-the-same-way-that-objects-can to make  `property` work on module level. Works fine, thanks!