# Why variable defined in a if else blocks can be used outside blocks?

Tags: python, variables, if-statement, scope, tensorflow

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


class simpleTest(tf.test.TestCase):
  def setUp(self):
    self.X = np.random.random_sample(size = (2, 3, 2))

  def test(self):
    a = 4
    x = tf.constant(self.X,  dtype=tf.float32)
    if a % 2 == 0:
      y = 2*x

    else:
      y = 3*x 

    z = 4*y

    with self.test_session():
      print y.eval()
      print z.eval()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  tf.test.main()
```

Here y is tensorflow variable and is defined inside the if else block, why does it can be used outside the block?

Comment: The "blocks" in python are **only** the *function* blocks.  All other statements do *not* produce a new scope. For example: `for i in range(5):pass print(i)` works, so the `i` of the `for` loop is leaked outside the loop.

Answer (score 6):

This is more general than [tensorflow](/questions/tagged/tensorflow), it has to do with [python](/questions/tagged/python)'s scope of variables. Remember this:

> Python **does not** have a block scope!<sup>*</sup>

---

Consider this trivial example:

```
x = 2
a = 5
if a == 5:
    y = 2 * x
else:
    y = 3 * x

z = 4 * y
print z     # prints 16
```

What I am trying to say is that `y` is not a local variable defined in the scope of the body of the *if statement*, thus it's OK to use it after the if statement.

---

For more: [Variables_and_Scope](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html).

<sub>*[Block scope in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167923/block-scope-in-python)</sub>

Comment: no specific reason for not upvoting it. if i had seen an issue i'd have downvoted it. anyway, i kind of miss an explicit mention of python not having a block scope

Comment: Good idea @ThiefMaster, I updated my answer, thank you very much!

Comment: @user2886263 any reason for not accepting the answer?