# In Python file handling, how does closed method recognize the file object after being closed by with statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm confused how the `closed` method on a file object can be executed successfully even after the file has been closed, as documented one of the tutorials.

```py
>>> with open('workfile') as f:
...     read_data = f.read()
>>> f.closed
True
```

I would expect the `f.closed` command to fail because the `with` statement should close the file and `f` should no longer be available. How is the program still able to recognize the `f` file object after the it is closed?

Also, shouldn't the name `f` exist only within the `with` block? How is the program able to recognize the object outside of the `with` block?

Comment: actually that's a thing with `with`, they don't create a new naming scope

Comment: Python doesn't do block scoping. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/6167923/4518341

Comment: Closing a file object referred to via the variable `f` does not (and fundamentally *cannot*) change the value of `f`; it still refers to exactly the same object.  That object is simply now in a state where most operations would return a "file is closed" error.  Accessing the attribute `closed` (note: it's NOT a method) works exactly the same before or after.

Comment: `with`, as many other things in python, follows a protocol. It's for managing context. Please read about context managers and experiment. Then things will be much clearer

Answer (score -1):

> How is the program still able to recognize the `f` file object after the it is closed?

It just works, but is that really so much of a problem? Variables are not meant to be reused, some might say. For those, it would be a useless feature. For others, it would be good, or just alright.

> [...] shouldn't the name `f` exist only within the `with` block? [...]

Probably.

> [...] How is the program able to recognize the object outside of the `with` block?

As a matter of fact, the object, in the source code, *exists* before (and out of) the nested block (just right before and out of it). So the language designers' choice, even maybe arguably, makes sense.

Comment: What do you mean by "upper"?