# Using for loop variable outside of the for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I don't understand how this is possible? Here I am using the value of `i` for the `for` loop, outside the `for` loop.

```py
for i, kv in enumerate(bucket): 
    k, v = kv  
    if key == k:
        key_exists = True
        break 

#here is the issue...

if key_exists:
    bucket[i] = ((key, value))
    print(i)
else:
    bucket.append((key, value))
```

Comment: VTR since OP [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611760/scoping-in-python-for-loops) is asking *why* Python doesn't have block scope. Instead could be a duplicate of [Block scope in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6167923/4518341) and/or [Short description of the scoping rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/291978/4518341)

Answer (score 10):

This is possible because Python does not have block scope. The variable assigned to in the `for` loop (`i` in your code) doesn't have its own narrower scope limited to just the `for` loop; it exists in the outer scope, so it remains available after the loop.

For example:

```py
for i in range(10):
    pass

print(i) # prints 9
```

The same is true of any other assignment inside the loop. Here, the variable `j` is visible after the loop, for the same reason: the `for` loop block is not a separate, narrower scope.

```py
for i in range(10):
    j = 17

print(j) # prints 17
```