# Why does `for k in [*dictionary]` assign k?

Tags: python-3.x

```
x, *y, z = range(1,10)
k = ['x', 'y', 'z']
d = {k:v for k, v in zip(k, (x, y, z))}
for k in [*d]:
    print(f'{k}: {d[k]}')
print(k)
>>> z
```

The following works fine for `k` but it automatically assigns `a` which I do not desire.

```
x, *y, z = range(1,10)
k = ['x', 'y', 'z']
d = {k:v for k, v in zip(k, (x, y, z))}
for a in [*d]:
    print(f'{a}: {d[a]}')
print(k)
>>> ['x', 'y', 'z']
print(a)
>>> z
```

**Question:**

1. Why k is `'z'` instead of `['x', 'y', 'z']`?
2. What does `for a in [*d]` do?

Comment: Why do you think it should be `['x', 'y', 'z']` instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the scope of a variable initialized in an if statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829528/whats-the-scope-of-a-variable-initialized-in-an-if-statement) (slightly different question, but same answer). Or this? [Block scope in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6167923/4518341)

Comment: This one specifically about the assignment target of the `for` loop: [Using for loop variable outside of the for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59296289/using-for-loop-variable-outside-of-the-for-loop/59296366#59296366)

Comment: so the `_` in `for _ in iterable` is not merely a placeholder but a legit pointer. It strikes me... Umm.

Comment: It's a variable. You use it inside the `for` loop's body no differently to any other variable. It just happens that because Python doesn't have block scope, the variable is still visible after the `for` loop. Using `_` as a name for a variable you ignore the value of is just a convention; it has no special significance in the language spec.