# Why does Python let me use variables assigned in a nested block without the "global" keyword?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why does this program work even if I do not define the `userInput` variable in the global scope?

```
intInput = True
while intInput == True:
    try:
        userInput = int(input())
        intInput = False
    except ValueError: 
        print('You must enter an integer.')

print(userInput)  # shouldn't this fail, since userInput was defined in a block?
```

Comment: A good discussion about this possible dupe question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3611760).

Comment: `userInput` is being defined in the global scope here; Python does not have block scope.

Comment: Note, for the future, that a question's title should *describe the question itself*; it shouldn't be about you, or about the general context of the question, but actually be a sentence that encapsulates the question in a nutshell, so people with the same underlying problem can find it and learn from its answers.

Comment: (OdedBD was kind enough to suggest an edit with a better title, and I'm happy to have been able to approve it).

Answer (score 1):

Your code works because python don't have `block scopes`. You can learn more about it on this thread: [Block scope in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167923/block-scope-in-python)

If you define your variable inside a while statement, it's the same thing as defining your variable at the global scope (in your case).

```
intInput = True
while intInput == True:
    try:
        # userInput here is global, because it's inside a while statement only
        userInput = int(input())
        intInput = False
    except ValueError: 
        print('You must enter an integer.')

print(userInput)
```

Basically, the variable declared inside a *"block scope"*, will have its scope from where it is being declared.

For example, if your code was inside a function, then the `userInput` variable would have the function's scope, and then, your code would generate an error:

```
intInput = True

def do_your_thing():
    while intInput == True:
        try:
            # userInput being declared here will have the function's scope
            userInput = int(input())
            intInput = False

        except ValueError: 
            print('You must enter an integer.')

# you are trying to access userInput outside its scope
print(userInput)
```

Now, if you try to run this code, you'll see the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "teste.py", line 28, in <module>
    print(userInput)
NameError: name 'userInput' is not defined
```

Comment: BTW -- I've simplified the code in the question to focus only on the OP's core question about variable scope. This makes the answer a bit less clear, unfortunate.

Comment: I edited the post to be more specific with the post's code now

Answer (score 0):

In Python you don't need to define the variables in the global scope. Everywhere you put `var_name = value` you have a new variable.

If you want to declare a global variable and then use it in function or class scope you should use the `global` keyword like this:

```py
test = 123
def func()
   global a
   print(a)  # 123
```

Comment: actually, you don't need global to read the variable. You'll need it only if you want to change its value

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is ok and you did define it globally since you put in in a loop instead of a function. If you defined it in a function then it would give you an error.