# error while assigning a new value to a variable

Tags: python, scope

I was working with scope in python

```
a = 10
{
    a = 33
}
```

and I got this error,

> File "", line 3
> a= 33
> ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

so it means block scope is only for functions in python?

Comment: its declaring a set

Comment: You should first work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) if not done yet.

Comment: i thought we can define a scope like we did in js

Comment: but yeah it's declaring a set.

Comment: how to define a block scope then?

Comment: could be declaring a dictionary if you changed the `=` to `:`

Comment: Python doesn't have arbitrary block scopes.

Comment: Each function defines a scope, each module has its own global scope, and there's a process-wide built-in scope. That's it.

Comment: Python doesn't use `{}` for creating statement blocks.

Comment: There is no set "declaration".  Set displays are expressions, and expressions cannot include assignments statements.

Comment: class definitions and comprehensions/generator expressions have their own scopes too

Comment: @kindall Class definitions do not (`class` statements generate temporary *namespaces*). Comprehensions and generators scopes are another manifestation of function scopes (as they are implemented with implicit anonymous).

Comment: If it looks like a scope and quacks like a scope... it's a scope.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def foo():
    a = 33
    print(f"Inside: {a}") # Inside: 33

a = 10
foo()
print(f"Outside: {a}") # Outside: 10
```

I think this example of function scope is the only way to get something like block scope in Python. Idea taken from OP and confirmed in
[Block scope in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167923/block-scope-in-python)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).