# Can modules have properties?

Tags: python, properties, module

Is it possible to add properties and special methods to modules?  I want to define a module such that importing it acts like a class instance, and the body acts as a class definition.  Essentially, it's to avoid ugly syntax like this:

```
import game
if game.Game().paused:
    print("The game is paused")
```

E.g. the game module would look like this:

```
_Speed = 1

@property
def paused():
    return _Speed == 0
```

And the file using it:

```
import game
if game.paused:
    print("The game is paused")
```

Also, is it possible to define special methods (such as `__call__`)?

To be clear, I do not differentiate between class/instance methods, since I'm using `game.Game` as a singleton/[borg](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66531-singleton-we-dont-need-no-stinkin-singleton-the-bo/) class.

I have tested using @property and defining `__bool__`, but neither acts as I hoped.

Edit (information on why I want to use a property):

I have a property `game.speed`, a function `game.paused()` and a function `game.pause(bool)`.  Essentially, I have a temporary variable used to store the game speed when the game is paused.  There is a private speed variable that is set to zero when the game is paused.  I never want the user to see the speed as being zero, and be able to modify the speed while the game is paused, so that when the game is resumed, it uses the new speed.

Comment: Why not just use `from game import Game`?

Comment: How would the properties work?  A metaclass?  How would the metaclass refer to the Game class?

Comment: I'm saying that if you use `from ... import` syntax, you *don't need* properties on the module.  People who use your module won't expect there to be properties on it, so if you drop the properties from the module and simply use `form ... import` in your own code, you get the same readability but your API will better conform to other programmers' expectations, which is a Good Thing.

Comment: I updated my post with more information.  I have values that are calculated, but should act as properties (as opposed to a function).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/880530/936083 -- Might this work if I add methods directly to the module object?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Python doesn't care that what's in `sys.modules` is actually a module. So you can just:

```
# game.py
class Game(object):
    pass

import sys
sys.modules["game"] = Game()
```

Now other modules that `import game` will get the `Game` instance, not the original module.

I'm not sure I recommend it, but it'll do what you want.

Comment: Whoa. That's some black magic.

Comment: It makes a certain kind of sense. A module, after all, is itself an instance of a class (`types.ModuleType`). You could actually write your `Game` class as a subclass of the module type, instantiate it, and then you'd have something that is basically a module. But as I said, Python doesn't actually check the type.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you want to avoid accessing items via the module. That's fairly easy to do.

These two are equivalent:

```
import game
if game.Game().paused:
    print("The game is paused")

from game import Game
if Game().paused:
    print("The game is paused")
```

Ok then, how about this:

```
# game.py

class Game(object):
    @property
    def paused():
        return True

game = Game()

# from your module
from game import game
game.paused
```

Comment: This syntax is ugly.  It requires me to write a class to use a singleton/borg pattern, for the methods to refer to members as either `self.*` or `Game.*`, and (for borg pattern) to use an initializer hack (to avoid re-setting members every call to `__init__`).

Comment: In response to your second one, it was something I was trying to do at first, but turned out to be problematic when I had game require one module, and that module then require the class instance from game.  It gives you an error like so: `ImportError: cannot import name game`

Comment: @Darthfett circular dependency? Or am I misunderstanding you? game imports X and X imports game?

Comment: In Python we "are consenting adults". `Game` isn't part of your interface here; the `game` instance is, so in the Pythonic view, there's no need for instantiation-control "patterns".

Comment: @Josh Smeaton yup, I couldn't remember that name.  At the time I actually use stuff from game, everything should already be fully defined, so it's just a problem if I want to import a global.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel my first comment was only written about the first part.  The second was added in an edit.

Comment: That second example is great. Basically the same benefits of the module having a property and no messing with Python internals. If you really want to indicate to users of the module that the `game` variable is the only thing they should import, you can prefix other items with an underscore; that will also filter them from `*` imports.

Comment: @jpmc26 you could also just define the `__all__` property in the module, so that only `game` is available.

Answer (score 3):

If all you are looking for is the syntax as you mentioned, then you can define a class and use class level attributes

`a1.py`

```
class Game(object):
    paused = True


>>> from a1 import Game
>>> Game.paused
True
>>> Game.paused = False
>>> Game.paused
False
```

Well, as you asked about the [Properties on Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128573/using-property-on-classmethods), then you can do something with property decorator and classmethod. Soemthing like this

```
class ClassProperty(property):
    def __get__(self, cls, owner):
        return self.fget.__get__(None, owner)()

class Game(object):
    stage = True
    @ClassProperty
    @classmethod
    def paused(cls):
        return Game.stage == True

>>> from a1 import Game
>>> Game.paused
True
```

Comment: The problem lies in using a property.  I want `paused` to be calculated, as it is never stored.

Comment: According to the answer you linked, it doesn't work for setters.  I tried to give an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) which is why I didn't mention this, but I do also need setters for other members of game.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't define the class with instance properties, define an instance of it as a global variable in the module, and `from... import` *that*?

Comment: Yeah, setters may not be possible in that way.How about using the Class variable for setting the state? Ofcourse, it is not symmetric and I would say your method of instantiating would be cleaner.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: as Josh Smeaton mentioned in the comments of his answer, I have circular dependencies.  `game` is sort of a glue class, where it calls other modules' methods which in return need information from `game`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is going to work. You'll need to import the module more than once and Python will execute its contents more than once. And that will reset the speed variable again. I think you're better off using a single Game class that stores the game's state. It will also keep your code a lot clearer and easier to follow.

Comment: I want the module to be executed once, the problem I'm having is creating a property interface for `paused`.

Comment: That's why your approach is not going to work. You'll need a class with properties to store or compute the state

Comment: I'm not against having a class, if I don't have to use it as a singleton/borg, and create an instance every time I want to use a value.

Answer (score 0):

good answer here:

http://jtushman.github.io/blog/2014/05/02/module-properties/

Use of proxy pattern to implement module wide property. Elegant.

```
class Proxy(object):
    def __init__(self, local):
        self.local = local
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.local(), name)

# aliasing for better syntax        
module_property = Proxy

class User(object):
    """Contrived User Object"""
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.name = kwargs.get('name', 'billy')
    def speak(self):
        print("Well hello there!")
    def say_hi(self, to_whom):
        print("Hi there {}".format(to_whom))

@module_property
def current_user():
  return User()
```

Then it can be used as property:

```
from login_manager import current_user, User

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print current_user.name
    current_user.speak()
    current_user.say_hi('lauren')
```

Article also mentions installable package (werkzerg project) extending this concept.