# Property method without class

Tags: python, class, properties

I have a next code

```
global_variable = 1

@property
def method():
    # Some magic, for example 
    # incrementing global variable
    global global_variable
    global_variable += 1
    return global_variable

print method
```

This code return

```
<property object at 0x28dedb8>
```

But I expect 2. Is it possible in python to use property decorator outside a class?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`@properties` are meant to be *instance* properties, defined in a class. E.g.:

```
class A(object):
   @property
   def a(self):
      return 2

b = A()
b.a
=> 2
```

If I understand, you're trying to define a module-property (or "global" property). There's no easy/clean way to do that.  See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880530/can-python-modules-have-properties-the-same-way-that-objects-can).

EDIT: you can also define a `classproperty`, to make your property more global-like (does not required an instance). `classproperty` is not a built in, but is easy to define.  Here's one way to define it:

```
class classproperty(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = classmethod(f)
    def __get__(self, *a):
        return self.f.__get__(*a)()
```

Now you can do:

```
class A(object):
   @classproperty
   def a(self):
      return 2

A.a
=> 2
```

Comment: is there any pip package with this classproperty decorator?

Comment: @igor, I am not aware of any.  You can simply copy-paste it.  It is only 5 lines.

Answer (score 2):

Observe the following code:

```
@property
def f():
    return 1

print f

class a(object):
    @property
    def f(self):
        return 2

print a.f
b = a()
print b.f
```

Output:

```
<property object at 0x7f892bfb11b0>
<property object at 0x7f892bfb1208>
2
```

@property only works properly on a class object that has been instantiated.