# How to remove static class variable using automodule with Sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, member, docstring, autodoc

I'm currently using Sphinx (first time using it) to build the docs for my modules and I have some classes which have some class variables that are initialized with a default value.

For ex:

```py
class ConfigSettings(object):
    """Class that manages a config file
    """    
    #: Contains the path to the config file (root dir of module)
    path = Path(util.getAbsCurrentPath('configfile.ini'))
```

When building the docs the variable is evaluated and it prints the full path to the file which I don't want (for security reasons).
Is there a way to not display the variable value but maybe only the annotation using Sphinx?

I tried various combinations of `.. autoclass:` and `.. autodata:` but none of them worked so far...

This is what I currently have in my build file:

```
Config module
----------------------------

.. automodule:: lib.config
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
```

Comment: `:noindex:` option in the second `.. autoclass:` was used only to prevent Sphinx from issuing a warning from documenting the YourClass twice with `.. autoclass:`, because that would cause a duplicate entry in the general index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way with Sphinx directives is using annotation or excluding the member.

Unless there is a strict need to stop variables from self-initializing on module import, it's incorrect to change your Python source because of the way you want to present it. If your Python source code is correct, then adapt your `.rst` file to customize presentation.

your_module.py

```py
from pathlib import Path


class YourClass:

    #: This comment is documented with the member.
    path = Path('your_path', 'configfile.ini')
```

your_module.rst (shows 2 possible ways).

```
your_module
===========

.. automodule:: your_module
    :exclude-members: YourClass

    .. autoclass:: YourClass
        :exclude-members: path

        In this example you use an annotation while excluding from autoclass.

        .. autoattribute:: path
            :annotation: ='write your path here'

    .. autoclass:: YourClass
        :noindex:
        :exclude-members: path

        In this example you simply exclude from autoclass.
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: this is indeed what i was looking for thank you !! with my tries i got very close to your solution but i was keeping getting warning for duplicates references simply because i was not excluding the class from the module!!

Answer (score 2):

You can workaround the problem by not evaluating the path at import time.  I think the best way to do that is using a [classproperty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17007928/2096752).

For example:

```
class ConfigSettings(object):
    @classproperty
    def path(cls):
        return Path(util.getAbsCurrentPath('configfile.ini'))
```

Comment: unfortunately even using your suggested workaround the value still get printed to the output