# Calculate string values dynamically

Tags: python

Say I'm storing settings in a Python file, like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# settings.py

import os

LOG_DIR = '/tmp'
LOG_FILE_MAIN = os.path.join(LOG_DIR, 'main.log')
```

Now, I include that file like so and change one of the values:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# main.py

import settings

settings.LOG_DIR = '/home/myuser'
```

When I print out a variable that relies on a (now changed) "reference" variable, I'll see that the value hasn't changed.

```
print(settings.LOG_FILE_MAIN)
```

Will return:

```
/tmp/main.log
```

Instead of:

```
/home/myuser/main.log
```

I understand why this is (Python has already calculated the strings value), but I need to work around it. Is there a way to achieve the desired result, other than creating a class and overriding the `__setattr__` function?

Comment: You could use a dictionary of values instead of just a string.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the fact that strings are immutable.

Comment: Indeed, it does not. My mistake.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880530/can-python-modules-have-properties-the-same-way-that-objects-can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has *already* executed the expression setting `LOG_FILE_MAIN`, and won't set it again just because you changed one of the inputs. The *result* of the expression is stored, not the expression itself.

You'll have to manually set the other variable again, or calculate it with a function at a later point, provided it is always to be calculated from `LOG_DIR`. E.g. `LOG_FILE_MAIN` should not be part of your settings, but always be calculated from settings as needed. I prefer low-tech approaches like that over the alternatives, which *do* require you to override the `__setattr__` function, or otherwise handle all key attributes as setters.

Another approach is to use [formatting operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings); define `LOG_FILE_MAIN` as a string that'll have the whole `settings` module applied as keyword arguments in a [`str.format()` call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
LOG_FILE_MAIN = '{LOG_DIR}/main.log'
```

and then every time you need to use `LOG_FILE_MAIN` do:

```
settings.LOG_FILE_MAIN.format(**vars(settings))
```

optionally applying a dir separator translation step to that too to make it platform-specific.