# Can modules have properties the same way that objects can?

Tags: python, properties, python-module

As the Q&A [Can modules have properties the same way that objects can?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880530/can-modules-have-properties-the-same-way-that-objects-can/58526852)

But I just want to use `y` as `module.y`, so I run

module.py

```py
import time
def __getattr__(name):
    if name == 'y':
        return time.time()
    raise AttributeError(f"module '{__name__}' has no attribute '{name}'")
```

main.py

```py
import time
from module import y
x = time.time()
print(x)
time.sleep(1)
print(y)
time.sleep(1)
print(y)
```

But the result of `y` won't change, It always equals to `x`.
How to solve the problem?

I expect `y` always return the current time.

Comment: `__getattr__` isn’t re-run every time you `print(y)`. You already got `y` once and saved it to a name. Only an *attribute access* evaluates the getter.

Comment: you could set y to `time.time` and then call  `print(y())` to get the behavior you want

Answer (score 1):

You might use external package [`mprop`](https://pypi.org/project/mprop/) to get desired effect, following way

mod.py

```
import time
from mprop import mproperty

@mproperty
def y(mod):
    return time.time()
```

main.py

```
import mod
import time

t1 = mod.y
time.sleep(1)
t2 = mod.y
time.sleep(1)
t3 = mod.y

print(t3-t2, t2-t1)
```

output of `python main.py`

```
1.0011167526245117 1.0011308193206787
```

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately, this way needs to be reassigned every time. `t2 = mod.y`, `t3 = mod.y`